# The reason for re-rendering when no props or state has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

we have a very simple app that only includes a `useEffect` that has a `console.log("first")` inside.
The problem is that I expect the `console.log("first")` to be printed only once when it is executed, but I don't know why the re-rendering happens and it is logged twice. Please guide me, thanks.

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("first");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kilby-yn38cj?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: don't remove `StrictMode`, effects run twice in development mode as a means of checking that effects are pure and perform proper cleanup.

Comment: The problem I have in the bigger program is that the apis are called twice, so if we are not developing, will this problem be solved? And how can I check this to be sure? @Mulan

Comment: in production mode the effect is not run twice

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature in [React 18's Strict Mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode), and this behavior is intentional. The main reason for this new feature is to remind the developers to add a cleanup function in their effect handlers. So basically the component is mounted twice, meaning it is mounted, unmounted, and remounted. Although, it is important to know that **this behavior is observed in development mode** only and this doesn't occur in production builds.
To verify the behavior in dev mode, add a cleanup function in your effect handler and try logging something. For instance:

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("first");

    return () => console.log("Unmount App");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now the order of logs will be as follows:

```
first
Unmount App
first
```

This way developers can ensure that the components are less prone to errors and proper cleanup is done while unmounting the component.
To understand this better, you can refer to [this](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#step-3-add-cleanup-if-needed) solid example demonstrated in the docs.
If you want to understand more about cleanups in effect handler, refer to [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-useeffect-cleanup-function/) article.

Comment: If the web application is published, will we still have this problem?
Thank you for sharing the information

Comment: Could you perhaps share how did you go about publishing your application? I assume you might've accidentally deployed a developmental build to your production

Answer (score -1):

The reason is the strict mode of react, which works only in developer's mode. Most of the time you can find the `<React.StrictMode />` component at the top level of your app. Simply remove this and there will be no such behavior.

Comment: Simply removing [Strict Mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#strictmode) can be considered bad practice as it is designed to help and fix potential problems, the OP also asked _why_